# Handling environment variables in flask with docker deployment

Tags: python, docker, flask

I'm setting up flask with docker. I've two ways to set environment variables, one in flask `.cfg` files and another in docker `.env` files.

I'm wondering which one is the better practice. Evaluating the pros and cons, if I move my environment variables to docker `.env` files, I would have to do `os.environ.get` at all the places in my application code, including handling of defaults which brings extra dependency inside application from os environment variables. On the other hand, adding environment variables like DB password, secret keys, etc inside flask config might not be a right idea, although all my environment variables and defaults would be at one single place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to settle for one or the other.

Is not an unusual practice to use environment variables for configuring every aspect of your application, including DB passwords. This is staring to be an often practice in container environments such as [Kubernetes](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/secret/) or using [docker secrets](https://docs.docker.com/engine/swarm/secrets/) as they give the ability of keeping critical information encrypted and mount it as an environment variable to your container.

You could directly check in your application for the values of the environment variables or another option is to have an entrypoint in docker that checks for those values and ends up creating a configuration file that you use in your application.
 This last option allows you to use environment variables to configure your application or if you don't want to you could directly mount a configuration file to your container skipping the envs completely.

This is used for example on the [logstash docker image](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/docker-config.html).

Answer (score 2):

Just to add to the great answer by Esteban Garcia, another good way is to use both. Have a configuration file, class-based configs are great here because you can take advantage of config inheritance, and have all non-sensitive options in there. For the sensitive stuff like secrets, database passwords, etc - define them right in the config with `os.environ.get` to extract these values from the environment. So it ends up looking like this:

```
class DefaultConfig(Config):
    TESTING = False
    DEBUG = False
    SECRET_KEY = os.getenv('APP_SECRET_KEY')
    SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = os.getenv('APP_DATABASE_URI')
```

This way you can keep using `app.config` and not have to do `os.environ.get` all over your app.

Answer (score 0):

This is my 2 cents to the subject.

**The problem**

I was working on porting a flask app to docker and wanted to move my `settings.py` config vars to env vars so they will be picked up by the container's env. This way, it's easier to deploy it on an external service like ECS just by setting env vars and the app will still the same.

Because I had a lot of config vars on settings.py and didn't want to set each of them by hand on the flask app creation, I came up with the following solution.

Also, I will be using docker-compose to execute all the containers.

**Migrate from .py to .env**

First thing is to move from python code to a syntax that is compatible with docker-compose. So, if you have this in `settings.py`:

```
# *****************************
# Environment specific settings
# *****************************

# DO NOT use "DEBUG = True" in production environments
DEBUG = True

# DO NOT use Unsecure Secrets in production environments
SECRET_KEY = 'This is an UNSECURE Secret. CHANGE THIS for production environments.'

# SQLAlchemy settings
SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = 'postgresql:///../app.postgresql'
```

Rename that file to **settings.env** and change the content to:

```
# *****************************
# Environment specific settings
# *****************************

# DO NOT use "DEBUG=True" in production environments
DEBUG=True

# DO NOT use Unsecure Secrets in production environments
SECRET_KEY=This is an UNSECURE Secret. CHANGE THIS for production environments.

# SQLAlchemy settings
SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI=postgresql:///../app.postgresql
```

Note that you have to remove all white spaces and quotes (doubles and singles)

After that, you need to load that file on the docker-compose.yaml file:

```
version: '3.1'
services:
    web:
        image: web-server
        env_file: path_to/settings.env
```

Then, when you create Flask app, do the following:

```
# Instantiate Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

for variable, value in os.environ.items():
    app.config[env_name] = value
```

---

**If you don't want to load all available env vars on flask**

You can add a prefix to the vars on `settings.env` like this:

```
YOURAPP_DEBUG=True
```

And then on the app creation:

```
# Instantiate Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

for variable, value in os.environ.items():
    if variable.startswith("YOURAPP_"):
        env_name = variable.split("YOURAPP_")[1]
        app.config[env_name] = value
```